# Calling the entry point of a separate EFI file from a UEFI bootloader

Tags: operating-system, uefi

I am looking to call a function from a separate EFI file from my UEFI-utilizing bootloader, both of which are in the same virtual hard disk. I've looked into both the [`LoadImage`](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/07_Services_Boot_Services.html#efi-boot-services-loadimage) and [`StartImage`](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/07_Services_Boot_Services.html#efi-boot-services-startimage) functions defined in the specification, but I cannot figure out how I am supposed to use the [`EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL`](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/10_Protocols_Device_Path_Protocol.html#efi-device-path-protocol) type to my advantage.

From my research, I've found that close to all examples or problems that other people have had are solved by using some `FileDevicePath` function provided in [EDK2](https://github.com/tianocore/edk2/blob/master/MdePkg/Library/UefiDevicePathLibDevicePathProtocol/UefiDevicePathLib.c#L688) and [GNU-EFI](https://github.com/vathpela/gnu-efi/blob/master/lib/dpath.c#L234), which I'm not utilizing at the moment as I find the learning experience of starting from scratch very interesting and enlightening. My observations have concluded that this `FileDevicePath` function is capable of smashing data related to the file path name and file media type into an `EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL` variable, but I am not sure how I can do this myself as both source code samples use "helper" functions and macros for "magic numbers". Namely, I'm struggling with understanding how the required data for the device path protocol structure (path, type attributes, length, etc.) fits into the [specification's declaration of the struct](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/10_Protocols_Device_Path_Protocol.html#efi-device-path-protocol). If somebody can point me in the right direction on this topic, I have massive respect for your intellect and knowledge using this system. Thank you all for taking time out of your days for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device path consists of one or more nodes. Every node is a struct with the same [header](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/10_Protocols_Device_Path_Protocol.html#generic-device-path-structures) but can contain different data after the header.
To iterate over the device path you have to advance *Length* bytes from the start of the header to get to the next one.
If the device path is valid, it is terminated with an end node of type *0x7F* and subtype *0x01* or *0xFF*. I have seen systems that use *0xFF* as end node type, you might check for that as well.

You need to get the device path of the parent device (the partition from which your bootloader was loaded) via the *EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL* protocol.
The field you need is *DeviceHandle*, use *HandleProtocol* or *OpenProtocol* to get the device path from this handle.

Create a copy of the device path, if you don't want to use the helper functions you have to iterate over the device path nodes until you find the [end node](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/10_Protocols_Device_Path_Protocol.html#generic-device-path-structures) to get the length. You need to add some space to the copy, so you can insert a [file path node](https://uefi.org/specs/UEFI/2.10/10_Protocols_Device_Path_Protocol.html#file-path-media-device-path).

Insert the file path node with the path to the efi file before the end node.

Call *LoadImage* with the new device path, and *StartImage* with the image handle returned by *LoadImage*.

Here is a EDK2 based sample, that tries to load and start another file from the same device/partition:

```
EFI_STATUS EFIAPI DevicePathLengthWithoutEnd(
    IN  CONST EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL* DevicePath,
    OUT UINTN* Length)
{
    UINTN TotalLength;
    UINT16 CurrentLength;
    CONST EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL* CurrentNode = NULL;

    if (DevicePath == NULL || Length == NULL) {
        return EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    *Length = 0;

    TotalLength = 0;
    for (
        CurrentNode = DevicePath;
        // You may want to check for the SubType also
        CurrentNode->Type != 0x7F;
        CurrentNode = ((CONST EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL*)(((UINT8*)CurrentNode) + (*(UINT16*)CurrentNode->Length)))) {

        CurrentLength = *((UINT16*)CurrentNode->Length);
        // Check for invalid nodes
        if (CurrentLength < sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL)) {
            return EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER;
        }

        TotalLength += (UINTN)CurrentLength;
    }

    *Length = TotalLength;

    return EFI_SUCCESS;
}

EFI_STATUS EFIAPI LoadFile(
    IN  CONST CHAR16* PathOnCurrentDevice)
{
    EFI_STATUS Status;

    UINTN PathSize;
    UINTN OriginalDevicePathLength;
    UINTN NewDevicePathLength;

    EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL* LoadedImage = NULL;
    CONST EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL* OriginalDevicePath = NULL;
    EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL* NewDevicePath = NULL;
    EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL* NodeHelper = NULL;
    UINT8* ByteHelper = NULL;

    EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle;

    if (PathOnCurrentDevice == NULL) {
        return EFI_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }

    // Get the size of the string (with \0) in bytes
    PathSize = StrSize(PathOnCurrentDevice);

    // Get the loaded image protocol from the current images handle
    Status = gBS->HandleProtocol(
        // ImageHandle parameter from UefiMain/efi_main
        gImageHandle,
        &gEfiLoadedImageProtocolGuid,
        (VOID**)&LoadedImage);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(u"%a:%d -> %r\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, Status);
        goto finish;
    }

    // Get the device path from the current images source device handle
    Status = gBS->HandleProtocol(
        LoadedImage->DeviceHandle,
        &gEfiDevicePathProtocolGuid,
        (VOID**)&OriginalDevicePath);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(u"%a:%d -> %r\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, Status);
        goto finish;
    }

    // Get the length of the device path without the end node
    Status = DevicePathLengthWithoutEnd(OriginalDevicePath, &OriginalDevicePathLength);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(u"%a:%d -> %r\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, Status);
        goto finish;
    }

    // You need the old path + the file node + an end node
    NewDevicePathLength = 
        OriginalDevicePathLength +
        sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL) + PathSize +
        sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL);

    Status = gBS->AllocatePool(
        EfiLoaderData,
        NewDevicePathLength,
        (VOID**)&NewDevicePath);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(u"%a:%d -> %r\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, Status);
        goto finish;
    }

    ByteHelper = (UINT8*)NewDevicePath;

    // Clone the old path
    gBS->CopyMem(ByteHelper, (VOID*)OriginalDevicePath, OriginalDevicePathLength);

    ByteHelper += OriginalDevicePathLength;

    // Insert the file node after the old path
    NodeHelper = (EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL*)ByteHelper;
    NodeHelper->Type = 0x04;    // 0x04: Media
    NodeHelper->SubType = 0x04; // 0x04: File
    *((UINT16*)NodeHelper->Length) = (UINT16)(sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL) + PathSize);

    ByteHelper += sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL);

    gBS->CopyMem(ByteHelper, (VOID*)PathOnCurrentDevice, PathSize);

    ByteHelper += PathSize;

    // Add the end node
    NodeHelper = (EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL*)ByteHelper;
    NodeHelper->Type = 0x7F;    // 0x7f: End
    NodeHelper->SubType = 0xFF; // 0xFF: End entire device path
    *((UINT16*)NodeHelper->Length) = sizeof(EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL);

    // Load and start the image
    Status = gBS->LoadImage(
        FALSE,
        gImageHandle,
        NewDevicePath,
        NULL,
        0,
        &ImageHandle);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(u"%a:%d -> %r\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, Status);
        goto finish;
    }

    Status = gBS->StartImage(
        ImageHandle,
        NULL,
        NULL);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status)) {
        Print(u"%a:%d -> %r\r\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, Status);
        goto finish;
    }

    Status = EFI_SUCCESS;
    goto finish;

finish:
    if (NewDevicePath) gBS->FreePool(NewDevicePath);

    return Status;
}
```

Comment: So the device path nodes simply contain headers describing the type and length of the node, and then "arbitrary" data regarding the contents? Also, regarding the file path node insertion, `OpenProtocol` is used to retrieve the loaded image protocol (which is like a function/collection of functions?), which then allows me to get the existing device path of the partition my bootloader resides on. Then, I insert a file path node at the very end, and I can call `LoadImage` and `StartImage` with the appropriate parameters. Is my understanding of this correct?

Comment: Yes, the device path nodes contain different data, the type of data is defined by the *Type* and *SubType* header fields. Chapter 10.3 (in the 2.10 spec) describes the different types. In your UefiMain you get a parameter named *ImageHandle* use OpenProtocol to load the *EFI_LOADED_IMAGE_PROTOCOL* from that handle. You need the *DeviceHandle* field from the returned protocol (a struct containing data and function pointers). And then use OpenProtol again to load the *EFI_DEVICE_PATH_PROTOCOL* from the *DeviceHandle*. Insert the new node before the end node.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I tried to do this (poorly) and it seemed to hang once I called `LoadImage` with the modified DevicePath. I copied the information from my DevicePath handle (which had the correct data) into a new buffer, but my result did not have the same data. Writing this comment, I now realize I only allocated 5 (the number of nodes my program finds) bytes to this buffer, instead of 5 multiplied by the size of the struct. Would this new approach be correct, or do I need to add all the lengths of the nodes to get the proper size? I'm still a little confused by these nodes.

Comment: You need to add all the lengths (don't forget the end node and your new node) to get the right size of the device path.

Comment: I made some progress since my last comment. I appear to have the data laid out correctly (at least it's printing correctly), but `LoadImage` now simply hangs and I cannot figure out why. Upon further inspection, nodes 1-4 (zero based out of 5 nodes) have absurdly large node types (0xC9, 0xEB, etc.) all larger than decimal 100 (so do the subtypes and lengths). My data must be very screwed up, I'll study my memory allocation sizes and copying lengths tomorrow as it's very late for me. Thank you for your continued replies, I apologize I'm very much a novice with UEFI having come from x86.

Comment: No need to apologize. You can post your code here or somewhere else (github,...) than I can take a look at it, or I can post a code example that does all you need.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/patrick-media/my_uefi/blob/main/efi.c) is my code, I have 147 lines of it plus my thoughts in the form of comments. My entire main file is >500 lines long, so I condensed it because it's messy and the rest of the program _should_ not interact with my provided code at all (it's right at the beginning). At your convenience, I would greatly appreciate a functional example or at least what I need to change in how I currently have it laid out. Also, I'm building the other file the exact same way as my bootloader. Again, thank you for taking your time to help me out here.

Comment: I have added the sample code. In your code you used LocateProtocol, you have to use HandleProtocol or OpenProtocol. LocateProtocol returns the first protocol that matches the parameters, this may not be the instance you need. You need to advance Length bytes and not always 4. Are you using EDK2 or gnu-efi?

Comment: Everything makes a lot more sense now, thank you very much. Maybe I’m going in way over my head but I’m not using gnu-efi or EDK2 regarding my actual code. If you were referring to the shell, I believe it’s EDK2’s TianoCore. I’m considering using one of the two  to avoid reinventing the wheel at every turn but I do have a vast appreciation for understanding what actually happens internally. Again, thank you very much, I will attempt to reimplement this idea.

Comment: Update: things make a lot less sense after writing the lines myself. Not any of the pointer or size stuff, but the `HandleProtocol` call to find the DeviceHandle is failing citing an invalid parameter. I have checked both the LoadedImage and its DeviceHandle and both are not NULL, and according to the specification, `HandleProtocol` will only return an invalid parameter error if such an argument is NULL. I quadruple checked my GUID, the last parameter should be NULL to begin with, and I even copied that chunk of your example line for line, and it still came out with an error.

Comment: Please update your github code with your modifications and provide the rest of the code that is needed to build an run the efi app.

Comment: I added my main file to my [GitHub repo](https://github.com/patrick-media/my_uefi/blob/f7ac5611c1a90ffecfe8feff45f5cd054687d24c/efi.c#L503) (link starts at line 503, the start of the two functions I added from your example since the above code is called from my main function, which is at the bottom). I even did a straight copy-paste, aside from changing some global variable names, and the same error occurred in the same spot.